# LNK 2019 C++ Error

Tags: c++

I have a NewTree class that's been defined in NewTree.h. When I make a new instance of NewTree in my main method, it throws an LNK 2019 error.

NewTree.h:

```
template <class T>
class NewTree
{
public:

treeNode<T> *current;
treeNode<T> *root;

NewTree();
~NewTree();
bool insert(T *data, treeNode<T> *parent);
treeNode<T> search(T *target);
};
```

Line to make new instance of NewTree:

```
NewTree<xml_node<>> *tree = new NewTree<xml_node<>>();
```

Why is Visual Studio giving me an LNK error?

Full Error:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall NewTree<class rapidxml::xml_node<char> >::NewTree<class rapidxml::xml_node<char> >(void)" (??0?$NewTree@V?$xml_node@D@rapidxml@@@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
```

Comment: can you provide the full error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template class has to be [implemented in the header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). I think this is the reason of the problem. This is the only thing I can conclude from the code you have provided.

Comment: I think you're right, with the error he added; the constructor is undefined.